# How can I force Minecraft to only spawn monsters from spawners?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm making an adventure map in Minecraft, so I've put a lot of mob spawners to make them spawn where I want them to, but they also keep spawning where I don't want them to spawn, messing up with mob and non-mob zones.

Lighting everything up is not a option, as most of the map is meant to be dark. Is there a way to do this, perhaps with a mod?

Answer (score 6):

[This](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19090066/minecraft/readme.html#spawn) mod might help. It's part of [zombe's modpack](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/91055-v100-zombes-modpack-26-mods-v58-upd-11dec/). You can disable mob spawning on man-made materials and other specific blocks. I'm not sure if your settings will carry, though.

You should also note that mobs can't spawn on glass, so try making the flooring glass, though that might ruin the map.

Comment: I've used that to spawn the enemies, however there are other monsters that spawn naturally. I want mobs only to spawn by the mob spawner and not naturally. Know something?

Comment: @Lord [This](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19090066/minecraft/readme.html#spawn) mod might help. It's a part of [zombe's modpack.](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/91055-v100-zombes-modpack-26-mods-v58-upd-11dec/)

Comment: @Professor I think it would be a good idea to replace your answer with what you've written in your comment.

Answer (score 5):

Mobs will only spawn on top of opaque solid blocks. Therefore, you can create surfaces which mobs will not spawn on using any block which is solid (that is, you can collide with it) and not opaque (that is, you can see through or past it), such as:

- single Slabs
- Stairs
- Ice
- Glass

Of these, I suggest you try slabs (and stairs) as your basic technique, as there are a variety of interesting design possibilities with slabs, and they come in several materials so you can have some variety. Note that a double slab is the same as a normal block and will spawn monsters.

Comment: Good to know, but I suppose this is not an option for OP.

Answer (score 5):

Use `/gamerule doMobSpawning false` and then the mobs will spawn only from spawners.

Comment: I can vouch for this answer. That command prevents mobs from spawning naturally. They will however, spawn from spawners, eggs, and commands.

Answer (score 0):

If you need such a high level of mob control, you may want to look into using Adventurecraft to make your map.

http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/120456-11-adventurecraft-npc-pathing-blocks-r1095/

It will give you control over most every aspect you could need control of, and allow for doing some things that will help you make a much better map!